# How do I set a timer for a Parse object?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to set individual timer for each parse (Parse.com) object so that the objects will disappear in a while. I am currently programming an iOS app. I will be appreciate that u guys can give specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read up on cloud code, and once you do, create a function that goes through your objects and deletes some based on your given parameters. On parse.com, you can schedule this function to run in intervals.